# Node.Js MSSQL Query Timeout Expired

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express

I am using Node Express API to run SQL queries to populate a dashboard of data. I am using the mssql-node package to do so. Sometimes it runs flawlessly, other times I get the following error:

`[Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Query timeout expired]`

I am creating a `poolPromise` with a `connectionPool` to the db, then I pass that object to my other controllers which run the specific queries to populate data. I run the server which initiates the db.js script and connects to MSSQL with a pool connection.

db.js:

```
// for connecting to sql server
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8'); 

// db config to connect via windows auth
const dbConfig = {
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server={my_server};Database={my_db};Trusted_Connection={yes};',
    pool: {
        idleTimeoutMillis: 60000
    }
};

// create a connectionpool object to pass to controllers
// this should keep a sql connection open indefinitely that we can query when the server is running
const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig)
                    .connect()
                    .then(pool => {
                        console.log('Connected to MSSQL');
                        return pool;
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err))

module.exports = { sql, poolPromise };
```

An example of one of my controllers and how I use the `poolPromise` object is below. I currently have about 7 of these controllers that run their own specific query to populate a specific element on the dashboard. The performance of the queries each run within 1-10 seconds (depending on current server load, as I am querying an enterprise production server/db, this can vary). As I mentioned earlier, the queries run flawlessly sometimes and I have no issues, but at other times I do have issues. Is this a symptom of me querying from a shared production server? Is it preferred to query from a server that has less load? Or am I doing something in my code that could be improved?

```
const { sql, poolPromise } = require('../db');

// function to get data
const getData = async (req, res) => {    
    try {
        // create query parameters from user request
        let id= req.query.id;
        
        // create query from connectionPool
        let pool = await poolPromise;
        let qry = `
            select * from tbl where id = @Id
        `
        let data = await pool.request()
                                 .input('Id', sql.VarChar(sql.MAX), id)
                                 .query(qry);
        // send 200 status and return records
        res.status(200);
        res.send(data.recordset);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Error:');
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
};

module.exports = { getData };
```

Comment: 1-10 seconds for single row reads is really slow. Are your tables correctly indexed? For example `select * from tbl where id = @Id` should have an index on `id`, most likely a clustered index. Why is `@Id` passed as `varchar(max)`, is that what the column is (bad idea)? It should be passed as the same data type as the column

Comment: For further help we need to see what indexes you have, and please share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. This is not answerable otherwise

Comment: @Charlieface I made a simple query for purpose of demonstration. I cannot share my company's db information. The SQL Queries are pulling from a prod db and is querying 100k+ rows per query. Each query runs in less than 5 seconds (some within a second). Its the query timeout error I am trying to understand why it happens sometimes and other times does not. In regards to your inquiry on varchar(max), that is again, purely for demonstration, in reality I am using strings that have limitations of varchar(20).

Comment: If you can't tell us we can't help you. SQL performance issues are very specific, there are not that many general rules of thumb. At a complete guess: someone else is writing to the table and locking it up, probably because of a poor query plan. Without further info everyone is just going to be guessing

Comment: @Charlieface my question is more aimed at my NodeJs connection and if I am creating any flaws by nature of connection via the pool object. In reality my queries are using several tables and again, if ran in SSMS, run in sub 5 seconds for hundreds of thousands of rows. I am seeking to understand the Query Timeout error and insights around what can cause such an error on one go, and when ran 2 minutes later, cause timeout. I can provide an anonymous query I suppose and update shortly. Additionally, I am not a DBA and do not have access to share query plan.

Comment: The cause of the error is that the server is waiting for data to come out of the query. There are all manner of things that can go wrong with SQL queries and cause performance issues, and diagnosing them is pretty difficult even without having both hands tied behind my back. How about you use a tool like SentryOne Plan Explorer to sanitize the query plan into an anonymous plan so no sensitive info is shown. If you are not a DBA then you probably don't have the right permissions to solve this anyway. You need to be able to create indexes at the very least

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for providing at least some guesses/insights. It helps to understand the possibilities of timeouts. I am but an analyst trying to work on a web application and understanding that the issue could be coming from a slew of items on the server side, I can work with an internal DBA to understand.